# spf record fail on forwarded mail

Tags: postfix, spf

I've set up Postfix, Dovecot and MySQL according to [this tutorial from linode](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql).  In the virtual aliases table I have an account which forwards to my gmail.

Because these messages are then being delivered through my mailserver, which obviously is not designated as a permitted sender by the spf record of the originating domain, the messages are marked as "spf: fail" and have the added header like "someone@example.com via myservername.com".

This makes perfect sense but I'm wondering if there is some way to deliver/forward these messages without the spf penalty?  For now everything is fine as I have added filters in gmail such that forwarded mail will not be marked as, and delivered to spam. But historically, mail providers have a tendency to change and often tighten policies in regards to mail delivery, so for that reason I'd like to know if there is a better way to configure this.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/a/1120558

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the answer is SRS.  Surprised nobody chimed in on this but figured I'd answer my own question as it may benefit someone else in the future.  I'm using this:
https://github.com/roehling/postsrsd