# Forwarding to Gmail account via Postfix: SPF record with a hard fail

Tags: postfix, spf, gmail

I run a Postfix server which forwards one address to a gmail address.

```
# /etc/aliases
localuser: remoteuser@googlemail.com
```

This works since several months. But if a sender has a SPF record with a hard fail, then the forwarding does not work:

```
  gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[ said: 550-5.7.26 The
    MAIL FROM domain [example.com] has an SPF record with a hard fail 550-5.7.26
    policy (-all) but it fails to pass SPF checks with the ip: 550-5.7.26
    [...]. To best protect our users from spam and 550-5.7.26
    phishing, the message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.26
    https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication for more 550
    5.7.26 information. -
    gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA command)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the OP's own answer, the solution is to install `postsrsd` to rewrite the sender's "Return‑Path: " header.

This full example on Debian 11 worked for me:

- `apt install postsrsd`
- Edit `/etc/default/postsrsd`:

  - Uncomment the line with `SRS_EXCLUDE_DOMAINS=` and add your domains, separated by space or comma:
    `SRS_EXCLUDE_DOMAINS=example.com,.example.com,example.org`
- `systemctl restart postsrsd`
- Edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to add

> ```
> # Use postsrsd to rewrite the Return-Path: header
> sender_canonical_maps = tcp:localhost:10001
> sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender
> recipient_canonical_maps = tcp:localhost:10002
> recipient_canonical_classes= envelope_recipient,header_recipient
> ```

- `postfix reload`

The suggested additional install of the "Postfix SRS forwarding agent" [Postforward](https://github.com/zoni/postforward) may not be necessary. It wasn't for me. Check it's description to see if you need or want it.

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution:

I installed `postsrsd` via apt.

I installed [Postfix SRS forwarding agent](https://github.com/zoni/postforward) via compiling localy and copying the binary to `/usr/local/bin/postforward`.

I changed the file

```
# /etc/aliases
someuser: "|/usr/local/bin/postforward -path /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin remoteuser@googlemail.com"
```

Call `newaliases`.

Now the email gets the SRS rewriting:

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=none (google.com: relayhost.example.com does not designate permitted sender hosts) smtp.mailfrom="SRS0=R4ZG=2W=example.com=sender@example.com"
...
Return-Path: <SRS0=R4ZG=2W=example.com=sender@foo.com>
```