Forwarding emails coming to my postfix server to their respective gmail accounts
I am not an experienced postfix administrator, so there may be a simple solution to my following problem:
I have a personal SMTP server running on Ubuntu 24.04 with postfix 3.8.6.
There are multiple email addresses defined on (say) mydomain.com and I forward emails coming to these addresses to their respective gmail accounts using a /etc/postfix/valiases configuration file which is something like this:
user1@mydomain.com  user.one@gmail.com
user2@mydomain.com  user.two@gmail.com
user3@mydomain.com  user.three@gmail.com
user4@mydomain.com  user.four@gmail.com
group1@mydomain.com  user.one@gmail.com, user.two@gmail.com
group2@mydomain.com  user.three@gmail.com, user.four@gmail.com
...

This configuration works most of the times, except for some emails coming from strict SPF configured email servers (say xyz@otherdomain.com). In this case, the gmail servers reject such forwarded emails with a message like this:

550-5.7.26 The MAIL FROM domain [otherdomain.com] has an SPF 550-5.7.26 record with a hard fail policy (-all) but it fails to pass SPF 550-5.7.26 checks with the ip: [a.b.c.d]. To best protect our users from 550-5.7.26 spam and phishing, the message has been blocked. For instructions on 550-5.7.26 setting up authentication, go to 550 5.7.26  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126#authentication d2e1a72fcca58-71ec144d346si5857955b3a.303 - gsmtp

Here a.b.c.d is the IP address of my SMTP (postfix) server. Obviously, gmail will not accept emails coming from my server's IP address and having at the From: (or actually the Return-Path:) field something like xyz@otherdomain.com.
To solve this, I am using the /etc/postfix/canonical configuration file like this:
@otherdomain.com       me@mydomain.com
@yetanotherdomain.com  me@mydomain.com
...

and thanks to this configuration postfix adds a header like:
Return-Path: <me@mydomain.com>

to emails coming from the above listed domains.
As a result, gmail accepts this email:
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of me@mydomain.com designates a.b.c.d as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=me@mydomain.com;
       dmarc=fail (p=REJECT sp=NONE dis=QUARANTINE) header.from=otherdomain.com

This works for the domains enumerated in the /etc/postfix/canonical configuration file, like I have shown above.
However, I need I more general solution to this that will cover all domains.
Please note that, my postfix server does control SPF records and rejects spam mails. So, I don't need the SPF check done by gmail. And the solution I need is a general method to forward all emails as if they are originating from mydomain.com. How can I do this in postfix?

Mail forwarding in the classical way breaks on SPF and related sender verification schemes. There are several approaches to deal with that such as for example SRS (Sender Rewriting Scheme)  explored in this Q&A https://serverfault.com/q/1113736/37681

Thanks @HBruijn The post at https://serverfault.com/a/1120558/503972 answers my question. I have implemented SRS as suggested there and have been monitoring for several days. All seem OK for now.

It looks like you're missing a DKIM Signature, which is why DMARC is failing.
Here some instructions: https://jackstromberg.com/2024/01/configuring-dkim-for-postfix/
You can also use an online DKIM Generator to generate the keys or openDKIM.

Thanks, but this is not what I am asking for.
